# LWJGL NVIDIA Driver Issue

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, lwjgl, nvidia

I have a GeForce GT 650M, and I recently updated to the 335.23 Driver (latest version). Doing so sort of messed up my LWJGL engine I have been making. First of all when I include this line:
`org.lwjgl.opengl.ARBTextureStorage.glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D (int)(Math.log(Math.max(decoder.getHeight(), decoder.getWidth()))/Math.log(2))+1, GL_RGBA8, decoder.getWidth(), decoder.getHeight());`

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Function is not supported
    at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.checkFunctionAddress(BufferChecks.java:58)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL42.glTexStorage2D(GL42.java:238)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.ARBTextureStorage.glTexStorage2D(ARBTextureStorage.java:22)
    at util.GLUtil.setUpTexture(GLUtil.java:255)
```

So I tried removing the parts that used this, and things still don't work. My SSAO component is plain white noise, my G-Buffer is black everywhere, and the final scene either looks like this:[image: screenshot]

I should mention that roughly the same thing happened with a driver update about two months ago. The previous time I could actually make out the scene, the only things wrong were the 5fps framerate, broken shadows, and inverted lighting. A new version was released in a few weeks and it was fixed. No OpenGL components of the engine have been changed for around 3 months.
Could someone tell me what's going on here? [I put a decent amount of work into this](https://www.youtube.com/user/auctoria88/videos) and I would prefer not to lose it all.

Comment: Why are you using the ARB extension of `glTexStorage2D` instead of the Core version of `glTexStorage2D` ? (This could be the reason)

Comment: @Vallentin I can't find a glTexStorage2D function not in org.lwjgl.opengl.ARBTextureStorage2D... also as I said, I still get very strange problems when I remove all glTexStorage2D calls.

Answer (score 1):

Have your tried rolling back your graphics driver?  Does this clear up the problem?

Comment: I have not and I think that would fix the problem, but I think that the latest drivers not working with LWJGL is a problem that needs addressing. Also I need the latest drivers to play certain games :P

Comment: I did a little more looking and I ran across a couple more issues similar to yours.  They either cited recent OpenGL library changes (moved from version 3.x to 4.x) or driver updates.  Obviously BF4 takes priority here; but, maybe try using an older/or newer version of GL?

Comment: I was relying on some of the newer stuff in my work, so this might make things a little bit difficult. Could you provide the links to the people with similar issues?